# Delay between each iteration of foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am making a simon says game. This function displays the current sequence. The problem with it right now is that it doesn't really go in a nice sequence, it kind of does everything at once. Say the colors are "blue", "red", and "yellow, they will all go off at the same time rather than in sequence. How can I fix this?

```
var displaySequence = function(){
    compSequence.forEach(function(color){
        $("#" + color).fadeTo(300, 0.5).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
    })
}
```

Comment: You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to stagger the display of each color in the sequence.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A none jQuery solution. You will need to use the array index to give the illusion of waiting between each call, however each function has ran already. What will happen is: show color 1 in 1 second, show color 2 in 2 seconds...

```
var displaySequence = function(){
    compSequence.forEach(function(color, index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#" + color).fadeTo(300, 0.5).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
        },
        1000 * index);
    })
}
```

adjust the 1000 * index to change the delay.

Comment: So you say this is non Jquery solution??

Comment: No more jQuery solution :)

Comment: this isn't supposed to work smh : https://scottiestech.info/2014/07/01/javascript-fun-looping-with-a-delay/

Answer (score 1):

I make use of the jQuery **delay** function

Here is a the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var compSequence = new Array("red", "blue", "yellow");

  var displaySequence = function() {

      $.each(compSequence, function (i, color) {
        // add delay
        $("#" + color).delay(i * 1000).fadeTo(300, 0).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
      });      
  }

  displaySequence();

});
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ku8kd11t/)

Comment: This works really well but once a duplicate color is added, it is delayed by a huge amount.

Comment: @Scriptomaniac, yes, since i = starts 0 to end of the array length, and the delay is multiplied by 1000 milisecs(1sec), to reduce the delay then you can adjust the multiplier value