# Adding setTimout to forEach

Tags: javascript

thanks in advance. 
I'm trying to loop over a basic array using `forEach` method and a combination of `setTimeout` function for each individual loop. my goal is to loop over the array so that every `2000` sec the console will log the following item in the array for example:

- currently I couldn't figure out how to do this.
- Is there a way to enter a Boolean statement to `forEach` method ?

```js
// Declaring vars
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

// looping over the array
numbers.forEach(number =>{
  setTimeout(()=> console.log(number), 2000 );  
})
```

thanks in advance to all :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay between each iteration of foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706861/delay-between-each-iteration-of-foreach-loop) — use the `index` parameter of `forEach` and multiply your delay with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the execution of the forEach loop is so fast the difference is in milliseconds ( < 1 ms). you can achieve it by following:

```
// Declaring vars
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

// looping over the array
numbers.forEach( (number,i) =>{
  setTimeout(()=> console.log(number), 2000 * i );  
})
```

so 1st one would be delayed 2 seconds, 2nd one would be delayed 4 seconds, ... and vice versa. The recursive option is good as well, it gives you more control over the execution.

Comment: Thanks bro total appreciation works great, but how does the `i` param takes place is it the `index` ?  this is what I get nativity ?

Comment: yes in JavaScript most of the iterative functions have second attribute as index. Have a look at [MDN Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax) it is a very useful api, i would recommend you to read it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it recursively:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function logNumber(index) {
  console.log(numbers[index]);
  if (index < numbers.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(()=> logNumber(index + 1), 2000 );
  }
}

logNumber(0);
```

Or use promise and async await:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
async function logAll() {
    for(n of numbers) {
        await logNumber(n);
    }
}

function logNumber(n) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log(n);
    resolve();
  }, 2000));
}

logAll();
```

Comment: Thanks bro total appreciation :) worked great, I need to get in depth with es6 looks intersting

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
    var i = 0;
    // looping over the array
    numbers.forEach(number =>{
      i++;
      setTimeout(()=> console.log(number), i*2000);  
    })
```

Comment: Hey Guys thanks to all really appreciate the help from all answers currently I cant give all any rep's, cheers help and worked from all answers you are amazing :))

Comment: @Osh No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

// looping over the array
var i =0;
numbers.forEach(number => {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(number), i * 2000 );
    i++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional `index` parameter of the [Array.prototype.foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) function callback.. Notice that as JavaScript arrays are zero-based you should use `++i` to increment

Code:

```js
// Declaring vars
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// looping over the array
numbers.forEach((n, i) => setTimeout(() => console.log(n), 2000 * ++i));
```

Comment: Thanks bro total appreciation :) , I couldn't understand how does the `i` parameter works  ?  is it referring to the individual number ?

Comment: In Javascript you can use `++` operator before or after the variable name

Comment: `++i` (pre-increment) means "increment the variable; the value of the expression is the final value"

Comment: cool I'v console logged it its basically the array `index` right ? so it more seance cheers

Comment: Yup, but.. I am not sure what can contain the array.. That's why I suggest to use the array's `index` and will work for any array zero-based array no matter what is the data in the array..